# How to generate a root certificate that works on Android's Chrome browser?

Tags: android, node.js, google-chrome, ssl, https

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030906/self-signed-certificate-only-works-with-localhost-not-127-0-0-1) asked how to specify the config file and the command such that I can connect to my web server on my local area connection via HTTPS.

I have figured that out and added the certificate to my Android phone's Trusted Certificate store, but for some reason Chrome on Android is still saying `"The identity of this website has not been verified. Server's certificate is not trusted."`

I think the issue might be that because it is not a root certificate, Android doesn't trust it still? I googled around and there seems to be some talking about how setting `basicConstraints` to `CA:TRUE` may solve it, but you may also need to use `Key Usage` as well?

I tried several permutations of the suggested approaches, but nothing seems to be working. My question is simple: what configuration do I need to use in order for Chrome on Android to accept my self-signed certificate as valid? I want to debug push notifications locally in my dev environment and they require HTTPS.

This is my current configuration for generating the certificates, which allows Chrome to connect (via `https://192.168.1.155:8080`), but still has it say "Server's certificate is not trusted". Is it possible to change it to rectify this error?

req.cnf:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = US
ST = VA
L = SomeCity
O = MyCompany
OU = MyDivision
CN = localhost
[v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = DNS:localhost,IP:192.168.1.155,IP:127.0.0.1
```

`openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -nodes -keyout key.pem -new -out cert.pem -config req.cnf -sha256 -days 3650`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot without going into each browser (like each device) and disabling certain security flags.

Is there a reason you aren't using Lets Encrypt?  Its free and the only downside for now is a 90 day cert, which you can script to update quite easily.

Comment: As far as I can tell what you're recommending isn't possible? https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certificates-for-hosts-on-private-networks/174